# Can std::function store a function with the wrong return type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
#include <functional>

int foo(){return 0;}

int main ()
{
  std::function<void()> fun = foo;
}
```

When compiled with clang/libc++, the following error is reported:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'int ()' to 'std::function<void ()>'
  std::function<void()> fun = foo;
```

However, g++ (4.8 and 5.1) is completely fine with it. So, is g++ right to discard the return type? Note that it seems to be related to the C++ library implementation, not the compiler.

Comment: [clang-3.8](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2erePvXciwusL7U3) compiles fine as well

Comment: Neither the dup nor the dup of the dup mentions [LWG 2420](http://wg21.link/lwg2420), which changes the rules here.